# The current operation timed-out after 15 seconds

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I've set up SharePoint Server 2013 farm with 2 WFE, 2 Apps and 2 sql servers, then configured Search Service application with custom topology and everything is working fine (topology indicators are all green).

After crawling the search center site (the only site present on the farm now), I tried to search on the search center but it returned the following error : The current opeartion timed-out after 15 seconds

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: I didn't face this problem before, for my interest search on google related to this issue.
I found one link on the same issue with solution. https://www.metrostarsystems.com/enterprise-it/sharepoint-2013-search-results-webpart-timeout/ Once glance on it, may be this helps to you.

Comment: Hi Nagababu, I read the article that you mentioned and I don't think it will solve my problem. In my case, the farm is a new one and there's only one document uploaded. It could be related to the webpart timeout only if I had millions of items.